# Java application and AMD processor issues

Tags: java, sockets, intel, serversocket

We have a windows application, which was tested on Windows XP, 7, 8, 8.1. Application consists of 2 parts: Bootstrap and main application. Bootstrap assures updates of the main app, and updates main app at a particular point. But users were able to force stop Boostrap process via the Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+ESC->processes) by killing a process named javaw. In that case main app would not update and elder version would be launched. To avoid such issue we introduced interface of Bootstrap with main application via Socket. Here are the VM parameters of Bootstrap when it starts:

javaw.exe -Xms75M -Xmx90M -Xincgc -jar bootstrap.jar

There is a class SocketServer in the bootstrap:

```
public class Provider {
    ServerSocket providerSocket;
    Socket connection = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;

    public Provider() {
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            providerSocket = new ServerSocket(54345);
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            sendMessage("Connection successful");
            do {
                try {
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    if (message.equals("bye")) {
                        sendMessage("bye");
                    }
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                    cnfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (!message.equals("bye"));
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                providerSocket.close();
            } catch(IOException ioef) {
                ioef.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try {
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (providerSocket != null && in != null && out != null && !providerSocket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                providerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main app is being started by Bootstrap via ProcessBuilder like so:

```
public static void communicate(Process process) {
    final BufferedReader stdOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("Windows-1251")));
    final BufferedReader stdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream(), Charset.forName("Windows-1251")));
    //InputStream
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = stdOut.readLine()) != null) {
                    debugOut(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                stdOut.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
    //ErrorStream
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = stdErr.readLine()) != null) {
                    debugOut(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                stdErr.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
    try {
        final Provider provider = new Provider();
        ExecutorService pEexec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Future<Void> FPExec = pEexec.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    provider.run();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        pEexec.shutdown();
        process.waitFor();
        debugOut("[MainApp] Exit");
        provider.stop();
        FPExec.cancel(true);
        debug("Destroy process");
        process.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void startApp() {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
        ...
        params.add("-Xms32M");
        params.add("-Xmx48M");
        params.add("-Xincgc");
        params.add("-cp");
        params.add(new File(pathToJar, "mainapp.jar").getPath());
        params.add("net.craftwork.mainapp.AppStart");
        params.add(licCode());
        ProcessBuilder procBuild = new ProcessBuilder(params);
        debugOut("[MainApp] Start");
        Process proc = procBuild.start();
        communicate(proc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There is a class SocketClient in the main app:

```
public class Requester {
    Socket requestSocket;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;
    static Future<Void> oExec;

    Requester() {
    }

    void run() {
        try {
            requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 54345);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());
            do {
                try {
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    sendMessage("bye");
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                    cnfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (!message.equals("bye"));
        } catch(UnknownHostException uhe) {
            uhe.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            oExec.cancel(true);
            CommonUtils.debug("Bootstrap not found. Exit.");
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                requestSocket.close();
            } catch(IOException ioef) {
                ioef.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try {
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main() {
        final Requester client = new Requester();
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        oExec = exec.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    client.run();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Socket Client is called when main application starts

```
public class AppStart {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Requester.main();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is all to it I do believe. Whole setup worked perfectly fine, even on slower computers. Problem is that after introduction of Socket interface we had major complaints from some users, reporting crashes. Took us some time to figure out the issue, but here is what we found: computers with Intel processors are perfectly fine, only ones with AMD processors crash. Crash normally happens within 3 to 15 minutes from the start of Bootstrap. When crash occurs resources of the computer are not fully used, processor workload is about 20-50% and RAM is quite free as well. When crash occurs user is only able to reset computer using hardware reset or power button, nothing else responds. All users have latest JAVA 1.7.0_51. Whether system is 32 or 64 bit does both crash (or not crash if it is Intel based). Please share your thoughts. May be someone had identical issues and could help me to figure this out.

Comment: What dies it crash with

Comment: Catch the exception when it crashes, log that exception's call stack, examine that to find out what line it's crashing in, examine your code to find out what it's doing on that line, fix it. Or if you can't fix it, come back to us with a much more specific question about why that line, in that context, is having trouble.

Comment: Of course we do log everything. In the main app all the logs are sent to System.out, Bootstrap catches all the events of main app and logs everything through System.setOut to a log file. But what we have here is a full stop of a system, when all the services are down and whole system does not respond,therefore we can not get not only logs for the app, but also system logs as well,even Windows logs are not written during the crash.First log entry we get after system restart is system was reboot.Due to that reason we do not have any extra information about which part of the code causes the issue

Comment: Our only clue is if we remove thread of SocketServer start in Bootstrap and Requester.main() in the main app, AMD systems do not experience such issue. And once again Intel systems do not experience any issues at all, issue is present only on AMD systems

Comment: Could be related to the famous Livelock bug - see http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-Phenom%20X4%209500%20-%20HD9500WCJ4BGD%20%28HD9500WCGDBOX%29.html

Comment: Use try with resources : it simplifies the code and makes it robust. then retest. You do not need to close if something is Closeable. Compile in java 8  if possible .